# cb_share_config won't run locally, DISPLAY error

Tags: codeblocks

I'm trying to run cb_share_config from an xterm to import some color themes using:

"sudo cb_share_config"

which results in:

"Unable to initialize gtk, is DISPLAY set properly?"

This doesn't make sense to me since I'm running it locally, not through ssh or anything. I didn't think I needed to set the the display. Everything I've searched for is related to connecting to a server, which I'm not doing.

Code::Blocks version 16.01
OpenSUSE Leap version 42.3

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I've solved the problem or rather avoided it altogether by just running the tool directly from a file manager (Thunar). I'm still not entirely satisfied with Windows-like solution but it works. If anyone has any insights as to why I couldn't run it through a terminal I'd like to hear it but I suspect it might be a better question for a linux board.